# Display blank if I start my computer first and then turn on my monitor

Tags: display, port, desktop-computer, displayport

If I turn on my monitor and then my desktop computer everything works fine, my if I turn on my computer first, when I turn on the monitor it acts as if it was not plugged in.

My monitor is an AOC G2460, my graphic card is an Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti and I'm running a Windows 10-Ubuntu dual boot.

My monitor is connected via a Display port.

Is this a problem related with the port which does not update? How can I solve it?

Comment: Also, how are you connecting the monitor (HDMI, VGA etc).

Comment: I updated the questiom. Feel free to ask further information if you need them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DisplayPort is only truly hot-swappable if *all* devices properly support the protocol (many don't, but few cover that in the regular consumer manual).
The only conclusion that can be drawn without delving deeply into the technical documentation for each device is that "one of them isn't compliant", so the only real 'fix' is to not treat it as though it is compliant.

Switch the display on first.

Comment: Thank you. If I won't get any further answers in one or two days... I will accept yours.